# R/dplyr: Grouping and mutating problem with sum function

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

I am working with a data set of planes in certain air corridors across different years, `df` looks something like this:

```
ID   Airline  Corridor Year Index_A
1244 American C1       2010 0.03
1253 Delta    C12      2011 0.43
1643 Delta    C1       2010 0.05
1375 United   C1       2010 0.21
1621 American C5       2016 0.02
```

Variable `Index_A` has a range of 0-1. `Corridor` is in factor format.

I am trying to calculate the sum of `Index_A` for every `Year` **and** `Corridor`. `Index_A` is set up in a way that for every `Year` **and** `Corridor` its sum must be less than 1.

This is where I am having trouble with my code. It looks like this:

```
df_final %>% group_by(Corridor, Year) %>%
                mutate(total = sum(Index_A)) %>% ungroup(Corridor, Year)
```

The problem is that for certain years `total` is outside the range, i.e. >1. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to address the issue.

Am I looking at this wrong? I'd appreciate any help and don't have a package preference. Thank you.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. Are you sure your data is correct and enforces the given rule? How much greater than 1 is it? Are you within machine tolerance of 1? It's hard to get exact values with floating point numbers on computers.

Comment: One possibility could be you have `plyr` loaded which is masking `mutate`, `plyr::mutate` doesn't respect the groups and gives the total sum. Can you try the same code with `dplyr::mutate` ? But you say that this is the condition only for certain `Years` so I am not exactly sure.

Comment: About to make that comment as well: `plyr` can disturb correct working of `group_by`. Otherwise, run your code and find the combinations of `year` and `Corridor` for which the sum is larger than 1. Remove all values other than these. You will be left with a smaller dataset which you can manually inspect for data quality issues.

Comment: @MrFlick unfortunately the numbers go up to 60 for some reason. It's inexplicable to me.

Comment: @RonakShah I didn't know about the plyr problem, that's really good to know! I have tidyverse loaded, do you think that might still be causing the problem?

Comment: @PaulvanOppen Thank's for your input! Do you have a suggestion for how to find the combinations where the sum is larger than 1?

Comment: After you do the mutate, use `filter(total > 1)` then take one of those rows and note the year and corridor. Then do `df_final %>% filter(Corridor=="C1", Year==2010)` or whatever value you see.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [`summarise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) instead of using `mutate`.

```
df_final %>% 
  group_by(Corridor, Year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Index_A)) %>% 
  ungroup
```